# Логотип в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css, оптимизация-сайтов, mobile-web

Доброго времени суток дорогие друзья!
В мобильной версии сайта появилась такая "шляпа".
Дублируется логотип с увеличением, если прокрутить страницу, то она исчезает и появляется при обновлении страницы.
Помогите пожалуйста.

[image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

HTML Блока с логотипом и CSS:

```
 <div class="container home-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="logo text-center">
                            <!-- LOGO -->

            <img width="528" height="70" src="images/Logo.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




@media (max-width: 768px){
.logo img {
padding-top: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: А в коде какой из них логотип десктопной версии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас там есть два `div`- а с классами `container home-container` - в нем мобильное лого, и `container` в нем то же есть лого.

Вот картинки.

Первое это большое лого которое ни в одном варианте как я увидел используется тогда когда скроллишь в низ и появляется меню. Это лого то которое в меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это второе которое вам нужно (маленькое). Оно и для десктопной версии и для мобильной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот этот `css` код избавит вас от бага шаблона.

```
.navbar-fixed-top>.container>.navbar-header{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас!!! Выручили